# NSArray with values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can I create an NSArray with values populated?

That is to say:

```
NSArray *name=[NSArray alloc];
// insert these values: raju, biju.ramu
```

Comment: Be nice. You were a beginner once.

Answer (score 21):

Use the NSArray initWithObjects method, remembering to put nil in as the last value:

```
NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"raju", @"biju", @"ramu", nil];
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need to modify an existing array, You must use NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
[name addObject: @"raju"];
[name addObject: @"biju"];
```

Comment: If he indeed wants to modify an existing array, you should use this as declaration;

NSArray *name_array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
// array stuff
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:name_array];
[names addObject: @"raju"];
[names addObject: @"biju"];

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `[array mutableCopy]` instead of the `alloc`+`initWithArray` approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{

    NSString *nm=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Raju %d",i];
    [name addObject:nm];

}
```

Comment: You forgot to `-init` your `name` array and you’re trying to mutate a non-mutable type. `-addObject:` is an `NSMutableArray` method.