# Insert 12 objects into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I wish to add 12 objects to a nsmutablearray, ready for the command InsertObject:atIndex:

There must be a quicker way than

```
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
```

Comment: Please search SO before posting a question. Check the Related links on the right side of this page.

Comment: Yes well i dont want to do this 12 times             [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];

Comment: @user393273: There is something called a for loop that will do what you need or even `addObjects:`. Check the iOS documentation.

Comment: @Evan, is this a dup question?

Comment: @taskinoor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949244/nsarray-in-iphone-programming, but simply utilizing the documentation would render this question useless.

Comment: Though I have answered the question, I agree that just checking the basic language syntax would solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"" count:12];
```

Comment: since when do we upvote solutions that lead to a `NSInvalidArgumentException`? `arrayWithObjects:count:` can only be used to convert c-arrays into NSArrays.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My bad. Didn't read the method documentation until the end. Sorry for the fuss ,)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    [self.YoutubeArray addObject:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.YoutubeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"",...,@"",nil];
```

if you use static data

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't actually NEED those empty strings, you're just setting up placeholders?

If so:

```
self.YoutubeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:12];
```

Otherwise:

```
self.YoutubeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", @"", @"", @"",
                     @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];
```

Comment: I think the name of `arrayWithCapacity:` is a bit misleading, because it doesn't add placeholder objects to an array. It just reserves enough memory so the pointers to the objects you add on your own are saved in a continuos piece of memory.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch, I agree with you.